# Why is my laravel controller freezing when usgin App::setLocale()?

Tags: localization, freeze, laravel-8

Laravel version: 8.44.0

web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AppController;

Route::get('/{locale}/business', [AppController::class, 'business']);


Route::get('/', function () {

    App::setLocale('pl'); //no problem here

    return view('home');
});
```

AppController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function business(Request $request, $locale)
    {
        // I checked that $locale has correct value at this point
        if (! in_array($locale, ['en', 'pl'])) {
            abort(404);
        }

        App::setLocale($locale); // this line seems to freeze the controller

        return view('business');
    }
}
```

The problem is when I call https://myapp.com/pl/business for example, the website just keeps loading forever until timeout.
However when I delete `setLocale` function in controller, page is displayed correctly.
When I use `setLocale` in `web.php` everything works.
Why is this function not working in controller and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea why my code wasn't working, but here is my (probably not very elegant) workaround.

web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AppController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/{locale}/business', function($locale, Request $request) {

    $controller = new AppController;

    if (! in_array($locale, ['en', 'pl'])) {
        abort(404);
    }

    App::setLocale($locale);

    return $controller->business($request);

});
```

AppController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function business(Request $request)
    {
        return view('business');
    }
}
```